# sorting gridview C#

Tags: c#, sorting, gridview

How to sort the grid view in Visual Studio based on 2 columns ?
Moreover, I am working on soccer league App , and I want to sort the teams in the groups (gridview) based on the highest points ,(If points are equals), then based on the less goal differences .

Comment: Are you talking about Windows Forms DataGridView? Or ASP.NET GridView?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to sort the `dataGridView1` by the `first column` you have to do this:

```
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can sort gridview using following line on aspx page

```
  OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting">
```